# Php Xpath - How to get a specific value?

Tags: php, xpath

How can I get just the currency value from a string bellow using php xpath?

```
<div class="detalheDir2">
<div class="preco">
R$
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(aZ427014992694557())</script>
24,90
</div>
</div>
```

I want to get just 24,90

I'm using the query

```
$xpath->query("descendant::div[@class='detalheDir2']/div[@class='preco']/text()", $child);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your desired text node is always in this position, you can use indexing like:

```
//div[@class='detalheDir2']/div[@class='preco']/text()[2]
```

If its always after the a `<script>` tag you can write:

```
//div[@class='detalheDir2']/div[@class='preco']/script/following-sibling::text()
```

If its always the last text node you can write

```
//div[@class='detalheDir2']/div[@class='preco']/text()[last()]
```

Maybe the fact that it contains a `,` could be the key:

```
//div[@class='detalheDir2']/div[@class='preco']/text()[contains(., ',')]
```

All of these work for your example, however variance in your input will make any of these break.

If you only know that it's there somewhere among the text nodes and only the format sets it apart from the others, you might be better off selecting all the text nodes and iterate through them, and matching with regexps on `textContent`.

Comment: The problem is when I use text() I receive just R$ if I remove the text() I receive R$ocument.write(aZ427014992694557())

Comment: I'm not sure how you call this exactly, [see this demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/13y9MG), this is how i would do it. The thing you get back from `$xpath->query()` is a `DOMNodeList` instance, if it contains more than one element you can use `foreach` to get to the individual `DOMNode`s.